# Cookies and session state in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to take the name the user types in and then display this on another aspx page using session state.

On the page where to user types the name the code I have is

```
Session["name"] = TextBox1.ToString(); //Store the session state in a variable called name from the text box.

Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
```

Now on page2.aspx I have tried calling this variable but nothing seems to work.

I have a empty label1 on the page so I want the name to be stored into the empty label

```
Label1 = Session["name"];
```

The error message is convert type object to System.Web.UI.WebControlers.Label

Comment: Beware of using `ToString()` since it would throw an exception if the session does not contain `username`; use `(string)Session["username"]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Session["name"] = TextBox1.Text.ToString();    

Label1.Text = Session["name"].ToString()
```

There are two errors: first, you've tried assigning the `Label1` variable, rather than the label's text, hence the error you got. `Session[key]`  returns `object`, while `Label1` is of type `System.Web.UI.WebControlers.Label`

The second one - you've set the value to `user` session value and tried accessing it via `username` variable.

Comment: This has solved the issue thanks, although now on page2.aspx instead of displaying the name it displays 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Text' I am guessing this means I am not saving the name correctly?

Comment: @JoshuaHornby updated. You've missed the `Text` on the page1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Session["username"]` is object type and could not be assigned to `label` with implicit cast. You would have a string in `Session["username"]` and calling `ToString()` will give that then you can assign username to label text property.

```
Label1.Text = Session["username"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to do this since it won't throw an exception if value is null:

```
Label1.Text = (string)Session["username"];
```

If you are sure that `username` is set than you can do this:

```
Label1.Text = Session["username"].ToString();
```